# Proof of Parallelism in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing

Scenario: I have been asked to prove that parallel execution in Apache Spark is true parallelism and not pseudo parallelism (just fast switching of tasks by CPU). The way i figured out to prove it is that if i can prove, each core (i have 8 cores in my machine) is executing one partition of data that i created (creating same number of partitions as cores available). Please correct me if i am wrong.

With the code attached below, I have been able to access the task information which is also available in logs to check that each partition is being executed as separate tasks. Does anyone have idea how do i access processor or core information to prove each partition is being worked on by a single core? Is there any other way to prove parallelism of Apache Spark?

```scala
def getMap() = Map(
  1 -> "uno",
  4 -> "test",
  5 -> "tiger",
  6 -> "delete")

def getList() = List(
  1 -> "one",
  2 -> "two",
  3 -> "three",
  4 -> "four",
  5 -> "five",
  6 -> "six",
  7 -> "seven",
  8 -> "eight",
  9 -> "nine",
  10 -> "ten")

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Parallel Join").setMaster("local[8]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val t2 = sc.parallelize(getList(), 8)
  val t1 = getMap()

  val bt1 = sc.broadcast(t1)
  t2.foreachPartition(p => {
    val tc = TaskContext.get
    val partId = tc.partitionId() + 1
    val taskId = tc.taskAttemptId()

    p.foreach(rec => {
      val filteredValue = bt1.value.filterKeys(_.equals(rec._1))
      val mappedFilterValue = filteredValue.map { case (k, v) => ("Key: " + k, " Values: " +(v, rec._2), " Task ID: " + taskId, " PartitionId: " + partId) }
      mappedFilterValue.foreach(println)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You are wrong. It may be the case but it doesn't have to be. Think about `cgroup` and system level limits instead.

Comment: @zer0323 can you please elaborate or provide any snippet that can explain your thoughts.

Comment: It is your homework but take a look at [cpuset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpuset.html).

Comment: "and not pseudo parallelism (just fast switching of tasks by CPU) "   Um, one can implement a CPU exactly this way, and people often do so.  Intel hyperthreading is essentially exactly this.  So how are you going to prove this in the face of counterexamples sitting in your laptop?